# posting into WordPress with WP API "code issue"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to post into a WordPress site using the WP API. I have the code below but it does not seem to be working, am not getting any post in my site.

```
<?php
$options  = array (
  'http' =>
  array (
    'ignore_errors' => true,
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' =>
    array (
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'user' . ':' . 'pass' ),
    ),
    'content' =>
     http_build_query(  array (
        'title' => 'Hello World',
        'content' => 'Hello. I am a test post. I was created by the API',
        'tags' => 'tests',
        'categories' => 'API',
      )),
  ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$response = file_get_contents(
    'http://freeglobaljob.com/wp-json/posts/',
    false,
    $context
);
$response = json_decode( $response );
?>
```

Comment: Which WordPress API are you trying to use, exactly? Looks like that's client code for the WP REST API plugin. Did you install that plugin? Also, to post code here, just paste it in, select it, and click the "code" button to format it as code.

Comment: thanks for editing the post, yes you are right, am working on posting to WordPress from remote site with the WP REST API, am yet to figure it out, any help will be appreciated.